What are the exact basic building data structures used in immutable.js to further build List, Stack, Map, OrderedMap, Set, OrderedSet?
Could anyone share more details about underlying algorithms used in immutable.js data-structures, so to understand time and space complexity? What type of trees are used (AVL? Red-Black? something else)? So essentially, i am keen to know more about guts of immutable.js.
Unfortunately official docs do not cover this question fully. I tried reading the source code, but have not figured out yet. So, thought that it will be valuable to others to have such answers.
